# Why is streaming source of an image not working?

Tags: c#, wpf, image, stream

I am using the following code to stream an image source:

```
        BitmapImage Art3 = new BitmapImage();
        using (FileStream stream = File.OpenRead("c:\\temp\\Album.jpg"))
        {
            Art3.BeginInit();
            Art3.StreamSource = stream;
            Art3.EndInit();
        }
        artwork.Source = Art3;
```

"artwork" is the XAML object where image is supposed to be shown. The code is supposed not to lock up the image, it doesn't lock it up alright, but doesn't show it either and the default image becomes "nothing"... My guess is that I am not properly using the stream, and that my image becomes null. Help?

UPDATE:

I am now using the following code which a friend suggested to me:

```
        BitmapImage Art3 = new BitmapImage();

        FileStream f = File.OpenRead("c:\\temp\\Album.jpg");

        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
        f.CopyTo(ms);
        f.Close();

        Art3.BeginInit();
        Art3.StreamSource = ms;
        Art3.EndInit();   

        artwork.Source = Art3;
```

For some strange reason, this code returns the following error:

> The image cannot be decoded. The image header might be corrupted.

What am I doing wrong? I am sure the image I am trying to load is not corrupt.

Answer (score 12):

I managed to solve the problem by using the following code:

```
        BitmapImage Art3 = new BitmapImage();

        FileStream f = File.OpenRead("c:\\temp\\Album.jpg");

        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
        f.CopyTo(ms);
        ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        f.Close();

        Art3.BeginInit();
        Art3.StreamSource = ms;
        Art3.EndInit();   

        artwork.Source = Art3;
```

Thanks everyone who tried to help me!

Comment: Thank you, making sure that my memory stream was reset to the beginning before using it elsewhere fixed my problem (that threw the same exception as yours)

Answer (score 1):

Disposing the source stream will cause the BitmapImage to no longer display whatever was in the stream. You'll have to keep track of the stream and dispose of it when you're no longer using the BitmapImage.

Comment: So, what should I do? You should note that I started programming in C# 1 day ago...

Comment: I had this same issue with BitmapImage and assigning BitmapImage.StreamSource to a memory stream that was being disposed (via using). I had to remove the using to preserve the JPG file. I previosly thought I had to use a JpegBitmapDecoder, but that isn't necessary. Thanks @rossisdead!

Answer (score 1):

This is probably simplier

```
BitmapImage Art3 = new BitmapImage(new Uri("file:///c:/temp/Album.jpg"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
        BitmapImage Art3 = new BitmapImage();
        using (FileStream stream = File.OpenRead("c:\\temp\\Album.jpg"))
        {
            Art3.BeginInit();
            Art3.StreamSource = stream;
            stream.Flush();
            Art3.EndInit();
        }
        artwork.Source = Art3;
```

Comment: No, that is not my problem, image is not being loaded at all from the source, that's what my problem at the moment is... :(