# Getting "The image cannot be decoded. The image header might be corrupted" error while reading list of images from WCF service

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, list, byte

I'm saving my images in the form of bytes in the database.When I try to fetch the images from database using WCF , it gives me the error **"The image cannot be decoded. The image header might be corrupted."**.For this , I have increased the size in web config.
Below is the code I'm using but I'm getting the same problem.Please Let me know where I'm wrong.

```
<bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="basicHttp" allowCookies="true"
                 maxReceivedMessageSize="20000000"
                 maxBufferSize="20000000"
                 maxBufferPoolSize="20000000">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="32"
               maxArrayLength="200000000"
               maxStringContentLength="200000000"/>
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
```

Comment: Doesn't seems to be related to WCF, refer http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/066b5e99-406f-4ac1-9c2e-473940faca09/bitmapimagestreamsource-from-encrypted-image-problem?forum=wpf  and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3688377/c-wpf-streaming-source-of-an-image-not-working

Answer (score 2):

In wcf need to add below code in order to get rid off this error

```
<bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding maxReceivedMessageSize="10485760">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647"
                         maxStringContentLength="2147483647"
                         maxArrayLength="2147483647"
                         maxBytesPerRead="2147483647"
                         maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
          <security mode="None" />
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
```

Also needs to add the same in app.config on client machine

```
<bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding maxReceivedMessageSize="10485760">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647"
                         maxStringContentLength="2147483647"
                         maxArrayLength="2147483647"
                         maxBytesPerRead="2147483647"
                         maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
          <security mode="None" />
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
```